# VBA Email Generator - Send Notice to Employee with Overdue Tickets

Tags: vba, ms-access, outlook, ms-access-2010

VBA Email Generator - Send Notice to Employee with Overdue Tickets

Trying to generate emails to notify user that their ticket is overdue. The program runs and generates the email, however if a employee has multiple tickets overdue, it sends them multiple emails as opposed to one with all overdue items.

Your help is really appreciated!!!!

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub SendSerialEmail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailTo As String
Dim nameemployee As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 6) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 6) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outStarted As Boolean

'Create the header row
aHead(1) = "Ticket#"
aHead(2) = "Summary"
aHead(3) = "Ticket Status"
aHead(4) = "Date Created"
aHead(5) = "# Business Days Open"
aHead(6) = "Assigned To"

lCnt = 1
ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
aBody(lCnt) = "<HTML><body><table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"


On Error Resume Next
Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
On Error GoTo 0
If outApp Is Nothing Then
Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
outStarted = True
End If


Set db = CurrentDb
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets")
Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets")

 Do Until rec.EOF
        lCnt = lCnt + 1
        ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
        aRow(1) = rec("ID")
        aRow(2) = rec("title")
        aRow(3) = rec("name")
        aRow(4) = rec("created")
        aRow(5) = rec("workdaysopen")
        aRow(6) = rec("full_name")
        aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
        rec.MoveNext
    Loop

aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table></body></html>"
If outStarted Then
outApp.Quit
End If

Do Until rs.EOF

emailTo = rs.Fields("email").Value
nameemployee = rs.Fields("full_name")

emailSubject = "Termination Tickets Overdue" & " - " & Date

emailText = Trim("Hi " & rs.Fields("full_name").Value) & ","

Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
outMail.To = emailTo
outMail.CC = "myemail@gmail.com"
outMail.Subject = emailSubject
outMail.HTMLBody = "<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI>" & "Hi " & nameemployee & "," & _
 "<br>" & "<br>" & _
"<BODY style=font-size:14pt;font-family:Segoe UI>" & "<b><span style=""color:#B22222"">Overdue Termination Tickets</b>" & _
Join(aBody, vbNewLine) & _
 "<br>" & _
"<BODY style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI>" & "<b><i><span style=""color:#000000"">**Please note that tickets are overdue.</i></b>"
outMail.Display

rs.MoveNext
Loop

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing
Set db = Nothing

If outStarted Then
outApp.Quit
End If

Set outMail = Nothing
Set outApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: That's going to take some work, but first, it looks like you are creating two different but identical recordsets. There is no need to do that. you can cycle through the recordset once, then use rs.movefirst and cycle through it again. I do see that the second Do...Loop does in fact create an email for every record in the recordset. Consider aggregating data on the email field in your query, and then use the aggregate query to send the email

Comment: I see that you are using ticket numbers as well, so perhaps an aggregate query, in itself, is not going to get you all the way there. Within your VBA you can do a couple of things, but maybe the best route is to use a recursive function and a collection object (or two or three) to aggregate all of the information for each email recipient. I think that your 'Answer' would be just too big for a single question in the forum

Answer (score 0):

I'll invite your to test the following code,  I've made a test of this code.

The idea is to check if an email address has already been used, in order to send a single email per user.

### **Send all tickets to all users with 1-single email per user**

```
Public Function IsEmailInArray(strEmail As String, arr() As String, lUbound As Long) As Boolean
  Dim i
  For i = 1 To lUbound
    If arr(i) = strEmail Then
      IsEmailInArray = True
      Exit Function
    End If
  Next
  IsEmailInArray = False
End Function

Public Sub so66016960SendSerialEmail()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
'Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailTo As String
Dim nameemployee As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String
Dim strQry As String
Dim aHead(1 To 6) As String
Dim aRow(1 To 6) As String
Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outStarted As Boolean

Dim strTable As String

'Create the header row
  aHead(1) = "Ticket#"
  aHead(2) = "Summary"
  aHead(3) = "Ticket Status"
  aHead(4) = "Date Created"
  aHead(5) = "# Business Days Open"
  aHead(6) = "Assigned To"

  lCnt = 1
  ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
  aBody(lCnt) = "<table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"


  On Error Resume Next
  Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If outApp Is Nothing Then
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    outStarted = True
  End If


  Set db = CurrentDb
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets")
' Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets")

'
' get listing table of all overdue tickets:
'
  Do Until rs.EOF
    lCnt = lCnt + 1
    ReDim Preserve aBody(1 To lCnt)
    aRow(1) = rs("ID")
    aRow(2) = rs("title")
    aRow(3) = rs("name")
    aRow(4) = rs("created")
    aRow(5) = rs("workdaysopen")
    aRow(6) = rs("full_name")
    aBody(lCnt) = "<tr><td>" & Join(aRow, "</td><td>") & "</td></tr>"
    rs.MoveNext
  Loop

  aBody(lCnt) = aBody(lCnt) & "</table>"
  '
  strTable = Join(aBody, vbNewLine)

  '
  'If outStarted Then
  '  outApp.Quit
  'End If
  '
'
' rewind:
'
  rs.MoveFirst
'
' now we reuse aBody() array as temporay array to used email addresses:
'
  lCnt = 0
'
  Do Until rs.EOF

    emailTo = rs.Fields("email").Value

    '
    ' if email is not yet used:
    '
    If (Not IsEmailInArray(emailTo, aBody, lCnt)) Then
    
      nameemployee = rs.Fields("full_name")

      emailSubject = "Termination Tickets Overdue" & " - " & Date

      emailText = Trim("Hi " & rs.Fields("full_name").Value) & ","

      Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
      outMail.To = emailTo
      outMail.CC = "myemail@gmail.com"
      outMail.Subject = emailSubject
    
      outMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI>" & _
        "Hi " & nameemployee & "," & _
        "<br>" & "<br>" & _
        "<b><span style=""font-size:14pt;font-family:Segoe UI;color:#B22222"">Overdue Termination Tickets</b>" & _
        strTable & _
        "<br>" & _
        "<b><i><span style=""font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI;color:#000000"">**Please note that tickets are overdue.</i></b>" & _
        "</body></html>"
     
      outMail.Display

      '
      ' memory the email address just sent:
      '
      lCnt = lCnt + 1
      aBody(lCnt) = emailTo

    End If
    
    rs.MoveNext
  
  Loop

  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

  If outStarted Then
    outApp.Quit
  End If

  Set outMail = Nothing
  Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

---

---

### To send email with only her/his own information, we ORDER BY email, like this:

```
Public Function send1Mail(ByVal outApp, ByVal strEmail2Use, ByVal nameemployee, ByVal emailSubject, ByVal emailText, ByVal strTable)
  Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
  
  Set outMail = outApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)
  outMail.To = strEmail2Use
  outMail.CC = "myemail@gmail.com"
  outMail.Subject = emailSubject
    
  outMail.HTMLBody = "<html><body style=font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI>" & _
    "Hi " & nameemployee & "," & _
    "<br>" & "<br>" & _
    "<b><span style=""font-size:14pt;font-family:Segoe UI;color:#B22222"">Overdue Termination Tickets</b>" & _
    strTable & _
    "<br>" & _
    "<b><i><span style=""font-size:11pt;font-family:Segoe UI;color:#000000"">**Please note that tickets are overdue.</i></b>" & _
    "</body></html>"
     
  outMail.Display

  Set outMail = Nothing

  send1Mail = 1

End Function

Public Sub SendSerialEmail2Each()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
'Dim rec As DAO.Recordset
Dim emailTo As String
Dim nameemployee As String
Dim emailSubject As String
Dim emailText As String
'Dim strQry As String
'Dim aHead(1 To 6) As String
'Dim aRow(1 To 6) As String
'Dim aBody() As String
Dim lCnt As Long
Dim outApp As Outlook.Application
'Dim outMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim outStarted As Boolean

'
' nRows: number of rows in the table
' strTable: html table
' strTableHeader: html table header
' strEmail2Use: email address to send message
'
Dim nRows As Long
Dim strTable As String, strTableHeader As String, strEmail2Use As String

'Create the header row
' aHead(1) = "Ticket#"
' aHead(2) = "Summary"
' aHead(3) = "Ticket Status"
' aHead(4) = "Date Created"
' aHead(5) = "# Business Days Open"
' aHead(6) = "Assigned To"

' lCnt = 1
' ReDim aBody(1 To lCnt)
' strTableHeader = "<table border='2'><tr><th>" & Join(aHead, "</th><th>") & "</th></tr>"
'
  strTableHeader = "<table border='2'>" & _
    "<tr>" & _
    "<th>Ticket#</th>" & _
    "<th>Title</th>" & _
    "<th>Name</th>" & _
    "<th>Date Create</th>" & _
    "<th># Business Days Open</th>" & _
    "<th>Assigned To</th>" & _
    "</tr>"


  On Error Resume Next
  Set outApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
  On Error GoTo 0
  If outApp Is Nothing Then
    Set outApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    outStarted = True
  End If


  Set db = CurrentDb
'
' ORDRER BY email is important here:
'
  Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets ORDER BY email;")
' Set rec = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT ID, title, name, created, workdaysopen, full_name, email FROM OverdueTerminationTickets")
  nRows = rs.RecordCount
'
' initialize:
'
  lCnt = 0
  strEmail2Use = ""
  strTable = ""
'
  Do Until rs.EOF
    
    lCnt = lCnt + 1
    
    '
    ' get email of the current record:
    '
    emailTo = rs.Fields("email").Value
    
    '
    ' if first record: save email address and name.
    '
    If (lCnt = 1) Then
      strEmail2Use = emailTo
      nameemployee = rs.Fields("full_name")
      emailSubject = "Termination Tickets Overdue" & " - " & Date
      emailText = Trim("Hi " & rs.Fields("full_name").Value) & ","
    '
    ' send the email if address changes:
    '
    ElseIf (strEmail2Use <> emailTo) Then
      '
      ' close the html table:
      '
      strTable = strTableHeader & strTable & "</table>"

      '
      ' send 1 single mail:
      '
      send1Mail outApp, strEmail2Use, nameemployee, emailSubject, emailText, strTable

      strEmail2Use = emailTo
      nameemployee = rs.Fields("full_name")
      emailSubject = "Termination Tickets Overdue" & " - " & Date
      emailText = Trim("Hi " & rs.Fields("full_name").Value) & ","
      
      strTable = ""
    End If

    '
    ' aggregate all records per user for tr's:
    '
    strTable = strTable & _
      "<tr>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("ID") & "</td>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("title") & "</td>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("name") & "</td>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("created") & "</td>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("workdaysopen") & "</td>" & _
      "<td>" & rs("full_name") & "</td>" & _
      "</tr>"
    
    
    '
    ' also send email at the last row of recordset:
    '
    If (lCnt = nRows) Then
      
      '
      ' close the html table:
      '
      strTable = strTableHeader & strTable & "</table>"

      '
      ' send 1 single mail:
      '
      send1Mail outApp, strEmail2Use, nameemployee, emailSubject, emailText, strTable
      '
    End If
        
    
    '
    ' move next:
    '
    rs.MoveNext

  Loop

'
' do this to save RAM:
'
  rs.Close
  Set rs = Nothing
  Set db = Nothing

  If outStarted Then
    outApp.Quit
  End If

  Set outApp = Nothing
End Sub
```

Tested data Screenshot:

[image]

Generating the following Outlook email Windows to click and send.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks my friend!!! Works perfectly. However, is there a way to filter out the records and send the user only his/hers records.

Comment: I tried the code above and for some reason it only sends 1 record. For example, if I have 5 records overdue and Maria has 2, I would like the program to send me an email with my 5 records overdue and send Maria her 2 records overdue. I REALLY appreciate your help with this!! You are awesome!!

Comment: Sorry, I've corrected some errors in the second code.